# XY Points incorrect on map (ArcGIS Javascript API 4.7)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Hopefully something silly I'm overlooking. I started building my map with this [sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-featurelayer-collection/index.html)

But once I started using my own data, it isn't appearing correctly on the map. Example: These coordinates [38.90309, -77.05070999] in Washington DC show up somewhere in Antartica, as do the other US coordinates.

I've read a little about specifying the coordinate system that is being used, and it seems that maybe that is the problem. But I can't find any documentation about how to do that in the JavaScript API.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just have the values reversed. When dealing with a point, ESRI expects the longitude(x) to be first, and latitude(y) to be second.  `[-77.0363403, 38.8894801]`

Comment: Holy cannoli! :) That's the best thing I've heard all day. You're right! Can't tell I'm new at this, huh?

Answer (score 2):

Your coordinates are incorrect.

Correct answer is

> view.center = [-77.05070999, 38.90309];
>
> https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#spatialReference